# Erro no bindParam do PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Tenho uma função de `UPDATE` que recebe tabela, array de colunas, de valores e o where, faço o tratamento:

```
//montar SQL
$totalValores = count($valores); //conta quantos valores
$expressao = null;
for($i = 0; $i < $totalValores; $i++)
{
    $expressao = $expressao.":coluna{$i}=:valor{$i},"; //monta minha expresao de bind :coluna0=:valor0 e assim por diante
}

$expressao = substr($expressao, 0, -1); // remove a última virgula

$tabela = "UPDATE ".$tabela." "; // vai montando minha sql
$expressao = " SET ".$expressao." ";// vai montando minha sql
if($where)
{
    if(!strstr($where, "'"))
    { //trata meu where caso ele venha sem aspas ''
        $arr1 = preg_split("/([^\w\s]+\s*)/", $where, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
        $where = "WHERE ".$arr1[0].$arr1[1]." '".$arr1[2]."' ";
    }
    else
        $where = "WHERE ".$where;
}   
else
    $where = NULL;
$sql = $tabela.$expressao.$where; // monta sql (ate aqui tudo bem)
```

Mais pra frente tenho:

```
echo $sql = $tabela.$expressao.$where; //verifica sql

if($conn = conectar()) // se conectar
{
    $stmt = $conn-> prepare( $sql ); //prepara
    for($i = 0; $i < $totalValores; $i ++)
    { //substitui os binds criados
        $stmt-> bindParam(":coluna{$i}", $colunas[$i]);
        $stmt-> bindParam(":valor{$i}", $valores[$i]);
    }

    $result = $stmt->;execute(); // executa O ERRO ESTA AQUI
    if ( ! $result )
    {
        var_dump( $stmt->;errorInfo() );
        exit;
    }
    echo "<br> ;Atualizado!</br> ;";
    $conn = null;
    return true;
}
```

A parte que omiti do código são apenas `else`s para tratamento de erros, ao chamar assim:

```
atualizar("usuarios",
         array("nome", "senha"),
         array("uuuu", "ssss"),
         "id = 24");
```

Tenho os erros

> Fatal error: in C:\wamp\www\teste\php\atualizacao.php on line 79

e

> ( ! ) PDOException: in C:\wamp\www\teste\php\atualizacao.php on line
>    79 Call Stack
>
> #   Time    Memory  Function    Location
>
> 1    0.0012  133528  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
>
> 2    0.0055  174544  atualizar( )    ..\index.php:17
>
> 3 0.1442  183776  execute ( ) ..\atualizacao.php:79

A linha 79 é justamente o meu `execute()`, alguém pode me ajudar? Já fiz isso com sucesso na função de inserção, e esse é praticamente cópia e cola dela, só que aqui tenho dois `bindParam`

Comment: você da bind nas colunas e nos valores?

Comment: Sim.. Ali em baixo tem a linha que dou bind em :coluna$i transformando no valor de $colunas[$i] e respectivamente com valores, e ambos tem dois elementos (nome e senha)

Comment: vc da bind duas vezes ...

Comment: Sim, não pode? Em um exemplo da internet estava com dois binds `:nome` `:email`.. No caso eu teria de "concatenar" os dois arrays sendo [0] =coluna e [1] =valor? Pra fazer em um bind so?

Comment: Eu desconfio que o número de binds não bate com o número de valores passado, o erro da sua pergunta parece uma exceção ... que não retornou nenhuma mensagem útil, `$stmt->errorInfo()` deveria retornar algo bem especifico e um SQLState.

Comment: Bate, coloquei o echo na sql, tenho duas :coluna e duas :valor, meu array de colunas e valores tem dois elementos cada.

Comment: Dentro daquele for(o segundo), deixe apenas `$stmt->bindParam(":coluna{$i}", $valores[$i]);`

Comment: também não deu, diz que falta tratar um bind, o :valor (que coloquei no primeiro for

Comment: Também fiz como te falei, juntando os dois arrays onde indice par seria minha coluna e indice impar seria meu valor, assim tendo só um bind,  mas continua o erro.

Comment: Você pode mostrar como chama essa função/método ?

Comment: Editei no post, e consegui resolver depois de reler a função inteira etc, vou postar a resposta, obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro se encontra na utilização do `bind`, que é suportado apenas para `values` e não `campos`(colunas) do banco de dados, logo o código certo ficaria assim:

**Primeiro `for`:**

```
for($i = 0; $i < $totalValores; $i++)
{
    $expressao = $expressao."{$colunas[$i]}=:valor{$i},";                        
}
```

**Segundo `for`:**

```
for($i = 0; $i < $totalValores; $i ++)
{ //substitui o bind criado
   $stmt->bindParam(":valor{$i}", $valores[$i]);
}
```

A query correta ficaria assim:

```
UPDATE usuarios SET nome=:valor0,senha=:valor1 WHERE id = '24' //Antes do bind 
UPDATE usuarios SET nome='uuuu',senha='ssss' WHERE id = '24' //Depois do bind
```

E não como estava antes:

```
UPDATE usuarios SET :coluna0=:valor0,:coluna1=:valor1 WHERE id = '24'
```

Pois, como já citei, não permitido uso de `bind` em campos ou colunas do banco de dados.